# How to remove rows based off the string in the first index pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove `rows` from a `pandas df`. Specifically, I want to keep everything the first `string` in `Col A` finishes in. So, for the `df` below, the `string` `finishes` with `Mon` so I want to remove any rows that don't finish with this value.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col 1' : ['val1-Mon','val2-Mon','val3-Tues','val4-Tues','val5-Mon','val6-Mon','val7-Mon','val8-Mon'],  
    'Col 2' : ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'], 
     })
```

This is easy enough for the `df` above by using the following.

```
df = df[~df['Col 1'].str.contains("Tues")]
```

But my input `data` changes every day. While I want to keep all `Mon` values today, I may want `Tues` values tomorrow. So I'd have to go in and manually update the day I didn't want.

The consistency is that first value. So if it ends in `Mon`, I want to keep everything ending in `Mon`. If the first row ends in `Tues`, I want to keep everything ending in `Tues` ect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need extract first value and then compare with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) or by [`str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html):

```
first = df['Col 1'].iloc[0].split('-')[1]
#if want check first today day
#first = pd.datetime.now().strftime('%a')
print (first)
Mon

df = df[~df['Col 1'].str.contains(first)]
#Jon Clements suggestion, thank you
df = df[~df['Col 1'].str.endswith(first)]
print (df)

       Col 1 Col 2
2  val3-Tues     A
3  val4-Tues     B
```

Comment: That Timestamp is redundant: `pd.datetime.now().strftime('%a')` is fine...

Comment: But it seems need check first value, so solution should be changed

Answer (score 1):

Create a day column by splitting on `'-'`, and then filter using `.iloc` to ensure we match the first row:

```
df['Day'] = df['Col 1'].str.split('-').str[-1]

filtered = df[df['Day'] == df['Day'].iloc[0]]

print(filtered)
```

prints:

```
      Col 1 Col 2  Day
0  val1-Mon     A  Mon
1  val2-Mon     B  Mon
4  val5-Mon     A  Mon
5  val6-Mon     B  Mon
6  val7-Mon     A  Mon
7  val8-Mon     B  Mon
```